# Users aren't able to run an Access 2007 app, after upgrading to Windows 10

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

We've got some MS Access 2007 apps here. I'm responsible for one. Normally, it never gives any problems. I haven't heard from the users of this app for over a year, until today. It was written years ago by someone (I don't know who) that is long gone, with little documentation. We're in the process of replacing all of our Windows 7 machines with Windows 10 machines. At first I thought that was the issue. However, one of my colleagues, who is responsible for a number of Access 2007 apps, said that his users are able to use their Access apps with no problem.

Looking back at the user's error, it says simply, "ODBC - call failed". No error number; just that. So, my next thought was maybe there was a missing DSN on the new Windows 10 machine. However, I asked the PC tech to check one of the working Windows 7 machines. He told me there were no DSN's in them. I'm not an Access developer, so I asked my colleague, who does do Access development, what he could discover. He found that the tables are all linked tables from a SQL Server database. Looking at what he was referring to (now that I know where to look) I saw what he meant. The connection to each of those tables uses trusted connections. They're all pointing to the correct SQL database server. That server is there. When I got into SSMS I could easily see data in the tables.

So, what could be causing that error to occur, especially since it doesn't look like it needs a DSN to make a connection to the SQL db?

Comment: You probably need to re-install or re-create your ODBC DSN's (Data Sources)... the likely would have been wiped out during your install. They are generally setup through: (Windows Key)  > type: `odbc` > "`Set up data sources (ODBC)`" There are several resources on this site and others detailing how to set it up in various scenarios.

Comment: What happens if you try to open a linked table directly from the navigation window? Do you get a better error message?

Comment: Are you also switching possibly between 32-bit and 64-bit? Windows 10 should not have issues but ODBC connections and drivers are different between 23-bit and 64-bit.

Comment: @Andre, when I try to open a linked table from my Windows 10 machine, I get the following error message: "ODBC -- connection to 'SQL Server Native Client 10.0<servername>' failed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume your Windows 10 is 64-bit.
And probably your Access is 32-bit.
Its important to know!
If my assumptions are correct, you need to use the 32-bit version of ODBC admin to setup the DSN.

- The 32-bit version is 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbc32.exe'
- The 64-bit version is 'C:\Windows\System32\odbc32.exe'

32-bit Access will look for a DSN setup using the 32-bit version of ODBC admin, even on a 64-bit OS. If you setup the DSN with the 64-bit version of ODBC admin, then a 32-bit Access will not see it!

Go back on the Windows 7 PC, and check exactly how the DSN is setup.
Is it a System, User, or File DSN?
Which drivers are installed for SQL Server?
(There are various different ODBC clients available for SQL Server.)
Replicate this DSN configuration when you create the DSN on Windows 10.

It sounds like you using the 'SQL Server Native Client' on Windows 7,
so make sure to install that on Windows 10.

See: [Installing SQL Server Native Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/applications/installing-sql-server-native-client?view=sql-server-2017)